# Angular UI Tree: Get old and new parent of node

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-tree

I created two trees and when I move a node from one tree to another I would like to know names of old and new tree. I added `data-tree-name="unsorted"` in `ui-tree` but I don't know how to access it. This is my code:

```
        <div ui-tree="treeOptions" data-tree-name="unsorted">
            <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="skill.unsorted">
                <li ng-repeat="sk in skill.unsorted" ui-tree-node>
                    <div ui-tree-handle>
                        @{{ sk.name }}
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>

         <div ui-tree="treeOptions" data-tree-name="sorted">
            <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="category">
                <li ng-repeat="cat in category" ui-tree-node>
                    <div ui-tree-handle>
                        @{{ cat.name }}
                    </div>
                    <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="cat.skills">
                        <li ng-repeat="sk in cat.skills" ui-tree-node>
                            <div ui-tree-handle>
                                @{{ sk.name }}
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
----------------------------------------------------
$scope.treeOptions = {
        accept: function(sourceNodeScope, destNodesScope, destIndex) {
            return true;
        },
        dropped: function(e) {
            console.log (e.source.nodeScope);
        }
    };
```

So how can I get `data-tree-name` value. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for [dropped](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree#droppedevent) event in official docs:

**dropped(event)**

If a node moves it's position after dropped, the nodeDropped callback will be called.

**Parameters:**

> - `event`: Event arguments, it's an object.
>
>   - `source`: Source object
>
>     - `nodeScope`: The scope of source node which was dragged.
>     - `nodesScope`: The scope of the parent nodes of source node when it began to drag.
>     - `index`: The position when it began to drag.
>     - `cloneModel`: Given data-clone-enabled is true, holds the model of the cloned node that is to be inserted, this can be edited before
>         drop without affecting the source node.
>   - `dest`: Destination object
>
>     - `nodesScope`: The scope of ui-tree-nodes which you just dropped in.
>     - `index`: The position you dropped in.
>   - `elements`: The dragging relative elements.
>
>     - `placeholder`: The placeholder element.
>     - `dragging`: The dragging element.
>   - `pos`: Position object.

Here is an example:

```
$scope.treeOptions = {
    dropped: function(event) {
        var sourceNode = event.source.nodeScope;
        var destNodes = event.dest.nodesScope;
        var sortBefore = event.source.index + 1;
        var sortAfter = event.dest.index + 1;
        var dataType = destNodes.$element.attr('data-type');

        // ...
    }
};
```

Comment: When I run console.log(dataType) I get "undefined" and instead of data-type I placed data-tree-name

Comment: @Alen It was taken from my project as an example. Modify it according to your situation.

Comment: This is how it works for me: var dataType = $(destNodes.$element.parent()).attr("data-tree-name");
Thank you very much for your help